# Access View in SharePoint 2010 and SP Designer Workflows on Change

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, list-view

Is there a way that when using a "Access View" view on a SharePoint 2010 list, that when i have a work flow to kick off on change, it doesn't kick off on a "per cell change" but rather a "per line/row change"?

Right now i open it up and make 4 changes in 4 different cells on the same line item/row i get 4 emails, i want just 1 email alert though.

Is there anyways I can edit multiple cells on one line without it sending multiple emails or even multiple lines but only get 1 email per line that had a change? anyone else ever have this problem?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, if its not possible with this view is it possible to have the workflow only run when a columns data is changed so like...

If Current Item:PONumber is not empty
and Current Item: SigREquired equals Yes
and Current Item: RecievedDelta is greater than (the previous value) of RecievedDelta
Email: Current Item:Created By

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I seemed to have figured it out. In the workflow, i told it to pause for 1 minute so if edit more than 1 cell on a row/line item, by the time the workflow kicks off, i only get 1 email alert, i guess its smart enough to take all the changes and send 1 email.